# How to implement a nested list using only cons pairs?

Tags: lisp, cons

I am making a pure Lisp interpreter, and trying to write a reader to convert lists to cons pairs.

From what I've read lists are internally cons pairs such as this:

```
( 1 2 3 ) = (1.(2.(3.NIL)))
```

but I have no clue how to implement a nested list such as the following with cons pairs

```
( (1 2) (3 4 ) (5 6 ) )
```

How is this supposed to look like unabbreviated?

Comment: You may find this question and its answer (disclaimer, it's my answer) useful: [Dot notation in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216711/dot-notation-in-scheme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be

```
> '((1 . (2 . ())) . ((3 . (4 . ())) . ((5 . (6 . ())) . ())))
'((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
```

or

```
? '((1 . (2 . nil)) . ((3 . (4 . nil)) . ((5 . (6 . nil)) . nil)))
((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951876/list-to-dotted-pair-notation) for a Scheme program (which is trivial to translate to Common Lisp) that prints a list as a dotted pair.

Answer (score 2):

```
CL-USER 40 > (sdraw::sdraw '( (1 2) (3 4 ) (5 6 ) ))

[*|*]------------------>[*|*]------------------>[*|*]--->NIL
 |                       |                       |
 v                       v                       v
[*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL   [*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL   [*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
 |        |              |        |              |        |
 v        v              v        v              v        v
 1        2              3        4              5        6
```